# Bash prompt special character not expanded in PS1

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc

I'm trying to set my [`PS1`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x157.html) environment variable based on runtime condition, so I use the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) to do so. Suppose I want to change my bash prompt based on `$?` value, my `.bashrc` would look like this:

```
function prompt_command() {
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        BASH_PROMPT="\W --->"
    else
        BASH_PROMPT="[\t][\u][\w] -x->"
    fi;
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
PS1='${BASH_PROMPT} '
```

I would like to make use of the [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html). Unfortunately, this does not work because the values are displayed as is.

Also, I need to use an intermediate `BASH_PROMPT` variable because some tools are modifying the `PS1` value. For example, while entering a virtual environment, `(venv)` is prepended to `PS1`, so I can't dynamically update `PS1` in `prompt_command` because that would overwrite the `(venv)`.

Why aren't these special values properly expanded and is there a workaround which does not imply spawning a subshell?

Comment: @Jesse_b `BASH_PROMPT` is set in `prompt_command` which is executed before each new line typed in my terminal, and before that the `PS1` variable is displayed. The `BASH_PROMPT` variable is properly expanded in my shell, but not special values like `\W` and `\t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why aren't these special values properly expanded?

`man 1 bash` says:

> Bash allows these prompt strings to be customized by inserting a number of backslash-escaped special characters that are decoded […]

(in your case `\t`, `\u`, `\w`, `\W`)

> After the string is decoded, it is expanded via parameter expansion, […]

So `\t` etc. are decoded first (but there are none in your `PS1`!), `${BASH_PROMPT}` is expanded later. From this expansion your backslash-escaped special characters appear but it's too late for decoding.

---

> Is there a workaround which does not imply spawning a subshell?

Yes. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37137981/10765659)

> Since Bash 4.4 you can use the `@P` expansion

Instead of `PS1='${BASH_PROMPT} '` invoke

```
PS1='${BASH_PROMPT@P} '
```

Now `$BASH_PROMPT` will undergo additional decoding consistent with the `PS1` original decoding.